# Print user input in txt file using C

Tags: c, input, output

What is the correct function to print two integers from user input to a "abc.txt" file ?
This is what I have tried so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>



 int main (void) {

FILE * fp;



 int num1, num2;
 fp = fopen ("abc.txt", "w+");
printf("Input two numbers : " );
fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &num1, &num2);

fclose(fp);

getch();
return(0);
}
```

Comment: There are more variants of the `printf` function, like [`fprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to print to a file.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("input 2 numbers:");
scanf("%d%d",&num1,&num2);
if(fp)
{
  fprintf(fp,"%d %d",num1,num2);
  fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made mistake in program. `fscanf` is used for reading from file so instead of `fscanf` use simply `scanf` and use `fprintf` to print integer in file as said correctly by user2438949.

Also don't forget to check for empty file pointer.